# How to add an arbitrary persistent DNS server at the top of resolv.conf as DHCP is on and resolvconf util is not an option?

Tags: linux, dns, dhcp

Good [whatever]ning all. The matter is in the headline above.

OS: CentOS 8 (*4.18.0-305.3.1.el8.x86_64*).

But first, several preconditions are:

1. A setting static ip's wether into *global-dns-domain* section of a **/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/[.conf]** file or into an interface settings is a bit lazy way.
2. As has already been said, the resolvconf util is also inappropriate.
3. The advice to straightforwardly add the ip's into resolv.conf leads to the contents being overwritten as soon as a reboot takes place.

P.S. I've already found the needed solution based on the following-like answers:
[How do I add a DNS server via resolv.conf?](https://askubuntu.com/a/134106/1349183)

but the solution using prepend command to be included into dhclient.conf has a serious flaw. That works as you use dhclient to reget dhcp settings manually and it doesn't after a reboot. On the next startup the resolv.conf has only the dns servers gained from a dhcp server rather than the locally set ones.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't networkmanager's GUI (or maybe also nmcli) allows you to set a DNS server for a connection profile whatsoever? (Although that might simply *overwrite* what the DHCP server gives, instead of like inserting one before that.)

Comment: @TomYan i haven't checked that, i believe it does overwrite what a dhcp server gives if you just set dns servers through the networkmanager's GUI or something alike. On the other hand the "prepend" solution, well, prepends the desired ones at the beggining of those like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some while i've managed to find out a workaround to get the added dns servers persistent. It turns out NetworkManager uses dhcp client instead of dhclient having been configured by me (according to the found "prepend" solution).

All it takes to get the method work is to set the two lines

```
[main]
dhcp=dhclient
```

into */etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/[your_config].conf*.

That's it, that does the trick.